# screenshot of all screens/monitors with greenshot

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, greenshot

I need to take screenshots of all my screens/monitors (whether I have one or 2; sometimes I'm working only from my notebook, other times I'm adding a monitor). I decided to use greenshot 1.2.10 build6 x64, so that I don't have to enter file names when saving. (windows 10)

I configured it so that when I press PrintScreen button, it captures the full screen; but this only makes a screenshot for the active/focused monitor ... is there a way to take one big screenshot with all my screens/monitors?

Thanks!
R

PS: I don't do regions/Internet Explorer screenshots

**UPDATE:** I want to setup Greenshot so that:
(1) I click one button (e.g. PrintScreen),
(2) all screens/monitors are included in that screenshot,
(3) a new file is saved having the date and time when the screenshot was taken, which includes all the screens/monitors. (this works already)
(4) I want to avoid creating screenshots for each screen; I want to avoid going into another program, paste, enter a name and save.

[image]

Comment: Key Description 
Prt Scn Copies the whole screen to the clipboard as a graphic or the screen with the mouse if using multiple monitors. Use MS Paint to paste the image. This is also known as Snap Desktop.
 
Alt + Prt Scn Copies the active window to the clipboard as a graphic. This is also known as Snap Windows. 

Ctrl + Prt Scn Copies the entire virtual screen when using multiple monitors to the clipboard as a graphic. Unlike the other two Print Screens above this one doesn't appear to have a name, or if so, it is not listed in the Windows' header files.

Comment: I've tested CTRL+PRNTSCRN (with Greenshot turned off) and it produces an all screen screenshot (provided that I'm pasting it in M$ Paint)

Comment: But this is not what I want; I want to setup Greenshot so that: (1) I click one button (e.g. PrintScreen), (2) all screens/monitors are included in that screenshot, (3) a new file is saved having the date and time when the screenshot was taken, which includes all the screens/monitors.

Comment: I want to avoid going in another program and pasting, inserting a name & saving.

Comment: I want to avoid going in each screen and taking a screenshot (I'll update the initial post)

Comment: Greenshot might not be the appropriate tool for this.

Comment: can you please recommend such a tool? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **WIN + PRT SC**. This will save a PNG file of your current virtual desktop, including all physical screens, to your Documents\Pictures\Screenshots dir. This is the result (my second screen is above the laptop screen, hence the layout):

[image]

This is a native Win10 function, no additional applications required.

Comment: man, this is awesome! Greenshot is about to leave my notebook :)

Comment: the screenshots have a number suffixed to them, so they won't overwrite ... which is nice!